# Configure Shruti fonts in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I am trying to install Shruti fonts for Gujarati, but I don't found a way to add them. I have added the Gujarati language form `Region & Language` tab, but not found a way to add Shruti fonts for Gujarati.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the desired fonts and extract it to a folder. (Gujrati Shruti fonts can be downloaded from here: https://www.wfonts.com/font/shruti)
2. Go to your Home directory in File manager. Press Ctrl+H to show hidden files in Ubuntu. Right click to make a new folder and name it `.fonts`, if not available already. That dot at the beginning is important. In Linux, if you put dot ahead of the file name, it hides the file from normal view.
3. Copy paste all TTF or OTF files in the downloaded/extracted directory to this folder.
4. Its done !!